# Layout and design regarding different sections of template when using MVC and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Bootstrap and AngularJS with .Net Web API for my backend services.  Im still a bit new to AngularJS.  When considering the different sections of the layout, my app directive is currently at the container level named "Bottom".  However, my individual views will be in the area named "main-content" (these are div boundaries).

The layout also contains an area named "sidebar" which will only be used on **one** page, the rest of my pages will expand "content-wrapper" from 10 to the full 12 column width of the page.

So Im trying to decide on how to use either use one layout (in terms of our MVC _layout.cshtml typically used for the template) for both types of pages, or use two separate layouts.  The latter seems "cleaner", since trying to use a single layout for all scenarios seems more trouble.  I think Ive used separate master pages with ASP.Net web forms in the past in these cases.  Same idea here?  I think this would make things cleaner also with regards to setting up the AngularJS code, as I can separate the two page types with different modules with their own controllers.  Does this seem like a good approach, considering not just the mvc layout, but any impact on Angular/Javascript code?

[image]

Comment: Are you building a single-page app? If so, you might have issues with having two separate server-side CSHTML pages.

Comment: Yes and no.  That was the direction I was headed.  After reading through a few demos and tutorials on building web apps with MVC & Angular, Ive modified that approach to use the SPA approach only on the "pages" that warrant it.  For others such as the login page and a few others, to just use MVC views.  So in other words, there will be several "pages" that will function as an SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use one layout CSHTML page.

It's hard to give a confident recommendation without having a deeper knowledge of your application. Ultimately, it's your decision to make based on the information you have.

That being said, if indeed that sidebar is only used on one page, it should be considered part of that page. With that in mind, `Container` in the image you attached would serve as the host element for the router's `view` directive and the page with the sidebar will have that sidebar in its template.

If, however, the sidebar may appear on other pages in the future, I would simply hide it based on the current page with the `view` directive on the `content-wrapper` in your example. I have a similar situation in an app I'm working in which the sidebar behaves as a sort of internal navigation. If the current page does not have any sensible links to put in that sidebar, we hide it. Something like that may work for you in this case.

In either case, I would recommend against using multiple CSHTML layout pages because of the potential strangeness in the user's experience with some pages using a nice, AJAX-driven navigation and others using an old-school, "white-flash" kind of navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ui-router, which is an alternative to the default routing that Angular comes with. It allows you to have multiple views, the content of which can change based on the route.  If you are used to using a templating system to layout applications pages and your pages have a generalized sort of layout (ie all pages have a top nav, a main body, and a footer, or something similar) then ui-router goes a long way towards making this much easier in Angular.